# My total is not updating in my loop

Tags: java, roman-numerals

I'm new to java and i am confused as to why the variable total is not updating.  When I print it it just prints the initial number of 0.  Also the method value returns numbers based on the roman character.  I left out the class line but that shouldnt matter.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double total = 0;
    String romanString = "MCMLXXVIII";
    double difference = 0;


    while (romanString.length() > 0 )
    {
        if (romanString.length() == 1 || value(romanString.substring(0, 1)) >= value(romanString.substring(1, 2)))
        {
            total = total + value(romanString.substring(0, 1));
            romanString = romanString.substring(1);
        }
        else
        {
            difference =  value(romanString.substring(1, 2)) - value(romanString.substring(0, 1));
            total = total + difference;
            romanString = romanString.substring(1);

        }
    System.out.println(total)   
    }

}

public static double value(String character)
{
    if (character == "I")
        return 1;       

    else if (character == "V")
        return 5;       

    else if (character == "X")
        return 10;      

    else if (character == "L") 
        return 50;      

    else if (character == "C")
        return 100;     

    else if (character == "D")
        return 500;     

    else if (character == "M")
        return 1000;

    return 0;
}   

}
```

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to debug your problem. Either use a debugger or sprinkle a generous supply of temporary println's throughout your code to see what your variables are doing as it runs.

Comment: What's `value()`? is it a method you developed?

Comment: This code is incomplete. Where is the `value()` function? Final `}` is not closed as well.

Comment: I updated it to add the value method.

Comment: ..and do yourself a favour, and call a string, a string, not character i.e. I mean, (String str), instead.

Answer (score 3):

A String is an object, so I think that in your `value()` method you would have to use `.equals()` to avoid comparing memory addresses. Currently, with `==`, `value()` will always return `0` as you are comparing 2 memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

All your problems come from your `valu()` method as I guessed, in fact the biggest problem is that you ara comparing strings with `==` instead of `.equals()`, `==` comparison is only used with primitive types.

You can get rid of this problem if you used `.equals()` or better if you used a `Switch` statement instead of all these `if` statements for comparing.

Another thing is that you used `double` as return type of your `value()` method while it would be better if you used `int`, as yu are always returning `int` value: `1`, `5`, `10`, `50`, `100`, `500` and `1000`.

This is how should your `value()` method be updated following these tips:

```
public static int value(String character){
    switch (character == "I"){
      case "I":
         return 1;             
      case "V":
         return 5;             
      case "X":
         return 10;             
      case "L":
         return 50;             
      case "C":
         return 100;             
      case "D":
         return 500;             
      case "M":
         return 1000;             
      default:
         return 0;
}
```

This will avoid having the previous mentioned problems in your code, you could also improve it better by `changingthe`type`of`character`from`String`to`Char`in your method as it will always hold a unique`character`along with using`Sting.charAt(i)` to get respective charcters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `equals` instead of directly using equals operator `==`.

In addition to that, Roman numbers represent integers. Using a [floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) [(`double` is a floating-point number)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) instead, is not a good practice.

```
public class Roman
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int total = 0;
        String romanString = "MCMLXXVIII";
        int difference = 0;


        while (romanString.length() > 0)
        {
            if (romanString.length() == 1 || value(romanString.substring(0, 1)) >= value(romanString.substring(1, 2)))
            {
                total = total + value(romanString.substring(0, 1));
                romanString = romanString.substring(1);
            } else
            {
                difference = value(romanString.substring(1, 2)) - value(romanString.substring(0, 1));
                total = total + difference;
                romanString = romanString.substring(1);

            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }

    }



    public static int value(String character)
    {
                      if (character.equals("I"))
                      return 1;

                      else if (character.equals("V"))
                      return 5;

                      else if (character.equals("X"))
                      return 10;

                      else if (character.equals("L"))
                      return 50;

                      else if (character.equals("C"))
                      return 100;

                      else if (character.equals("D"))
                      return 500;

                      else if (character.equals("M"))
                      return 1000;

                      return 0;
      }


}
```